# How can I select product quantities with product packs?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

RDBMS: MariaDB 10.1.44

My database structure is as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
   id int primary key auto_increment,
   name varchar(255),
   is_pack tinyint(1)
);

CREATE TABLE cart
(
   id int primary key auto_increment
);

CREATE TABLE cart_item
(
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  id_cart int not null,
  id_product int not null,
  quantity int not null default 0
);

CREATE TABLE product_pack
(
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  id_pack int not null,
  id_product int not null,
  quantity int not null default 0
);

alter table cart_item
    add constraint cart_item_cart_fk
        foreign key (id_cart) references cart (id);
alter table cart_item
    add constraint cart_item_product_fk
        foreign key (id_product) references product (id);
alter table product_pack
    add constraint product_pack_pack_fk
        foreign key (id_pack) references product (id);
alter table cart_item
    add constraint product_pack_product_fk
        foreign key (id_product) references product (id);
        
INSERT INTO product (name, is_pack) VALUES ('Product 1', 0);
INSERT INTO product (name, is_pack) VALUES ('Product 2', 0);
INSERT INTO product (name, is_pack) VALUES ('Product 3', 0);
INSERT INTO product (name, is_pack) VALUES ('Product pack 1', 1);

INSERT INTO cart () VALUES ();

-- My cart contains 1x Product 1, 2x Product 3 and 2x Product pack 1
INSERT INTO cart_item (id_cart, id_product, quantity) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO cart_item (id_cart, id_product, quantity) VALUES (1, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO cart_item (id_cart, id_product, quantity) VALUES (1, 4, 2);

-- Product pack 1 "contains" 2x Product 1 plus 2x Product 2
INSERT INTO product_pack (id_pack, id_product, quantity) VALUES (4, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO product_pack (id_pack, id_product, quantity) VALUES (4, 2, 2);
```

[DB Fiddle MCRE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tCyeYhK7GgbAnUePs6KUL/0)

---

I have a table `cart_items` which represents an association n..n between `cart` and `products`. Selecting those cart items is trivial, but I face a problem. I implemented product packs, which are "meta-products" not visible by the user and contains some other products, in a defined quantity, and I can't find how to select the sum of the quantities of each non-pack product in my cart.

E.G

I have a pack `Pack 1` that contains 2x `Product 1` and 2x `Product 2` - Let's say I have 1x `Product 1`, 2x `Product 3` and 2x `Pack 1` in my cart. Then I want my query to return :

```
----------------------
product   | quantity |
Product 1 |        5 |
Product 2 |        4 |
Product 3 |        2 |
----------------------
```

I tried `JOINING` ON my product pack table as I could :

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN p.is_pack = 0 THEN p.id ELSE pp.id END) as id
       , (CASE WHEN p.is_pack = 0 THEN p.name ELSE cp.name END) as name
       , (CASE WHEN p.is_pack = 0 THEN ci.quantity ELSE pp.quantity * ci.quantity END) as quantity 
       FROM cart_item ci
       JOIN product p 
       ON ci.id_product = p.id
       LEFT 
       JOIN product_pack pp 
       ON pp.id_pack = p.id
       LEFT 
       JOIN product cp 
       ON cp.id = pp.id_product
```

But of course I can not get one line per product and `SUM` without `GROUPING BY product.id` (can I ?) and I can't achieve this group. I get this error :

`Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.p.is_pack' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: You only have pack4

Comment: And to what does `quantity` in `product_pack` refer?

Comment: Seems like your edit came over mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT id_product, SUM(quantity)
FROM (SELECT CI.id_product, CI.quantity
        FROM cart_item CI
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                           FROM product_pack PP
                          WHERE CI.id_product = PP.id_Pack)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT PP.id_product, CI.quantity * PP.quantity
      FROM cart_item CI
      JOIN product_pack PP ON CI.id_product = PP.id_pack) X
GROUP BY id_product;
```

Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tCyeYhK7GgbAnUePs6KUL/0).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with a `left join` and some conditional logic:

```
SELECT COALESCE(pp.id_product, ci.id_product) as id_product,
       SUM(ci.quantity * COALESCE(pp.quantity, 1))
FROM cart_item ci LEFT JOIN
     product_pack pp
     ON ci.id_product = pp.id_pack
GROUP BY COALESCE(pp.id_product, ci.id_product);
```

Comment: @Altherius . . . That is why I provided the answer.